# Make multiple texts in one paragraph html

Tags: html, css, paragraph

Trying to get these two div's in one paragraph, does anyone have a solution?

```
<div class="boxed">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
</div>

<div class="boxed">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. 
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. RIght now it is very unclear what you mean. Perhaps use CSS as display:inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you want to insert two `<div>`'s in a single `<p>`?

If so its quite simple:

```
<p> 
   <div id="div1"></div>  
   <div id="div2"></div>
</p>
```

This obviously wraps two `<div>`s in a single `<p>` (paragraph). Then just add the inline css class to your `<div>`s:

css style for inline:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.inline { float:left; }
  .clearBoth { clear:both; }
</style>
```

Now just add the `inline` class to both your divs:

```
<div id="div1" class="inline">test</div>  
<div id="div2"class="inline">test</div>
```

Output:

```
testtest
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry about my unclear question, im new to this site sorry. What i was trying to tell is I have 2 div boxes and im trying to align them next to each other.

Comment: No problem, I had the same problem when I first joined - I was asking bad questions and then I learned how to write 'SO Approved' questions. See my updated answer

Comment: Yea, i just found out how to add a html to your question. Thanks for the help your answer worked! :)

Comment: Building this site www.musicon.6te.net/request.html trying to make it look some nicer but the site is not functional yet, having much troubles.

Comment: You should use bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/